# Make elements stop overlapping in flexbox

Tags: html, css

I have the image and the logos and the problem is that if I resize the window the logos end up overlapping the image of the portrait and I'm not too sure how I can set it up so that the logos are fixed relative to the portrait?

Here's the code.

```css
/* Defaults for Main Part of Pages */

body,
div,
h1,
p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.page {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: auto;
  height: 100vh;
}

.page--darkmode {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: auto;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #282434;
}


/* Homepage section */


/* Circle and Picture for homepage */

.content-container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.circle {
  top: 20%;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 2px rgb(155, 155, 155);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.circle--darkmode {
  top: 20%;
  width: 16rem;
  height: 16rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #282434;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 2px black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.circle-image {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.logos {
  width: 12rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 55%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.logo-link {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
}
```

```html
<div class="page--darkmode">
  <div class="content-container">
    <div class="circle--darkmode">
      <img class="circle-image" src="source" alt="Portrait of User">
    </div>
    <div class="logos">
      <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/william-wei-0196a7209/">
        <img class="logo-link" src="link" alt="Link to Linkedin">
      </a>
      <a href="https://github.com/weiwi21">
        <img class="logo-link" src="link" alt="Link to github">
      </a>
      <a href="https://github.com/weiwi21/weiwi21.github.io/tree/master">
        <img class="logo-link" src="link" alt="Link to github">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm kind of hard coding a lot of the relative positioning and it isn't really friendly for window resizing so I'm not too sure which changes I should make

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For such a simple layout there are a plenty of unnecessary stylings. However **removing the absolute position for the circle and logos** does stop the overflowing, but causes new problems with responsivity. Also thats not a big deal, you just have to change the hard-coded size of the circle to something responsive.

```css
body,
div,
h1,
p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.page {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: auto;
  height: 100vh;
}

.page--darkmode {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: auto;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #282434;
}


/* Homepage section */


/* Circle and Picture for homepage */

.content-container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.circle {
  top: 20%;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 2px rgb(155, 155, 155);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.circle--darkmode {
  top: 20%;
  /* hard-coded
     height: 250px;
     width: 250px; */
  height: calc(10vh + 10vw + 30px);
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #282434;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 2px black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.circle-image {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.logos {
  width: 12rem;
  top: 55%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.logo-link {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
}
```

```html
<div class="page--darkmode">
  <div class="content-container">
    <div class="circle--darkmode">
      <img class="circle-image" src="source" alt="Portrait of User">
    </div>
    <div class="logos">
      <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/william-wei-0196a7209/">
        <img class="logo-link" src="link" alt="Link to Linkedin">
      </a>
      <a href="https://github.com/weiwi21">
        <img class="logo-link" src="link" alt="Link to github">
      </a>
      <a href="https://github.com/weiwi21/weiwi21.github.io/tree/master">
        <img class="logo-link" src="link" alt="Link to github">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Quick question, for this same code, the circle ends up getting squished because of a lack of space, how would I fix it so that it keeps the circle shape even if its running out of space

Comment: I will try to make a demo. Please give me some time. Thank you :)

Comment: Well, how would you fix that the circle is running out of space? You need to change your 250px width and  height to something that adapts to stretched space. In your example I would propose to add aspect-ratio: 1/1 to your circle, than the height or width will be auto-computed from the other aspect.

Comment: Now we need to add the size to our square (mean circle :D). I used responsive units based on the window size - thats the adaptation from comment above. To ensure that it adapts to resize on both axes you need to use height: calc(x vh + y vw). Also there is a trick, when the size of the window is small, the circle will be very small. For this reason, add some pixels to your calc method.

Comment: Check the snippet, now the circle is responsive :)

Comment: I tried the changes that you suggested and they worked very well. Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem. I was glad to help you. Happy hacking :thumbup :D